# hashicorp waypoint cannot add variables in project name

Tags: waypoint

Someone can tell me if I can add var on project name please ?

```
project = "${var.env}"
```

error output when using **waypoint init**

```
[xxxx@xxxx finess-api]$ waypoint init
❌ Error loading configuration!

! /home/xxxx/waypoint.hcl:2,25-28: Unknown
  variable; There is no variable named "var"., and 1 other diagnostic(s)
! Project had errors during initialization.
  Waypoint experienced some errors during project initialization. The output
  above should contain the failure messages. Please correct these errors and
  run 'waypoint init' again.
```

- 

```
variable env {
    type = string
    default = ""
}
```

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to template the project name; however instead of templating the project name, I recommend using workspace-scoped operations, with one workspace for each "env" you're using.

https://developer.hashicorp.com/waypoint/docs/lifecycle/scope

Comment: Hello, yes hashicorp team reply to my post. This is not in scope and they don't want to active this option. For workspace method I think it's only work with non free version and i'm using free version :D. Thx for help dear